# How is this summation expression transformed?

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem, decimal-expansion

I am solving one math problem. I could not understand the following transformation described below. I am guessing the denominator is re-written as a factorial of 2K and unnecessary even terms are canceled by the numerator. But, I have no idea how the transformation is done. I would appreciate if you could clarify the transformation step by step

$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1\times 3\times ...\times (2k-1) }{2^{k}(k!)}x^{k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}\times (k!)^2}x^{k}$$

Comment: are you sure about the denominator?

Comment: In the fraction, what would happen if you were to multiply above and below by all de even numbers from 2 to _k_?

Comment: I think there is some typo : the left $2^{2k}$ term should be $2^{k}$ : then the right term will be Correct. Can OP check with the textbook to confirm that ??

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$(2k-1)!!=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!} $$
where $(2k-1)!!$ denotes the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).